# From gitlab to github

Tags: github, gitlab

I have a repository on a gitlab (University-own), and since there was no data limit, we uploaded a couple of heavy files (jupyter notebooks).
This work is for a scientific paper, and the journal is asking us to make the code available. Which we want. But they are pushing for us to have the code on github.

The final work does not have too-heavy files, but when pushing everything to github, the system refuses because of some large files in the history.

So, my question: is there a good practice in how to manage repositories on different websites?
My first answer to them was "but the gitlab is fine enough". But then I realized that there is no automatic Zenodo update, which is why they are requesting github (or at least pushing for something different than gitlab)

Would it be OK to remove the history and just put the code on github? Some of the work has been done by a student, and we would prefer if they keep the ownership of the changes.

Comment: Idk would it be a good thing to do or not, but you could create a branch and squash all the commits to a single one and then upload that branch to github, it will preserve the line changes/author info.

Answer (score 0):

Large files should be managed using [Git Large File Storage](https://git-lfs.github.com/) for your large files. [Migrate to using Git Large File Storage](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/topics/git/lfs/). Then migrate to Github. This will also make cloning the repository much faster and use much less disk space.

Answer (score 0):

So, I found a way around my problem:

I used [filter-branch](https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo)  to remove from history all the large files (since they were not of interest for the project at the end), and I was able to upload the project on github.

I had a look at the Git Large File Storage, but I was not able to understand everything from it. So deleting history (based only on file size, so that not all the history was deleted) seems to be the best in my case.